# Can changing members of values of HashMap cause java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, exception, hashmap, concurrentmodification

The below code is throwing concurrent Modification exception , the line where the exception is pointing is the first line of for loop

```
private synchronized void updateAllCacheValues() {
        for (Map.Entry<Configurations, SalesConfiguration> entry : ConfigurationCache.entrySet()) {
            Configurations conf = entry.getKey();
            SalesConfiguration saleConfiguration = ConfigurationCache.get(conf);
            Map<String, String> newMap = generateKeyValueMapFromConfigurations(conf);
            lastLoadTimestamp = new Date();
            saleConfiguration.setMap(newMap, lastLoadTimestamp);
        }
        logger.debug("Successfully updated all cached configurations., cache size " + ConfigurationCache.size() + "LAST_LOAD_TIME" + lastLoadTimestamp);
    }
```

Below is the exception trace

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1429)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1463)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1461)
at com.learning.java.daily.updateAllCacheValues(ConfigurationLoader.java:237)
at com.learning.java.daily.updateAllCacheValues.impl.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfigurations(ConfigurationLoader.java:156)
```

I am not able to guess what could have caused this exception , because I wrote a sample test where I am modifying the attributes of the value of Map but concurrent modification exception did not appear.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete example. You must have a class as well as all variable declarations so that we can compile and run the code ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, I will not be able to include the whole code for this ..

Comment: I did not ask for all of your code. Just include an example which reproduces the exact problem you need help with. The current code example will not compile because there is no class and there are missing variable declarations.

Comment: From reading through your code a couple of times, I’m surprised by this exception, I would not have expected it. Would be wonderful if you would [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the rest of us to play around with.

Comment: It may not be relevant: When doing `SalesConfiguration saleConfiguration = ConfigurationCache.get(conf);` you’re ignoring the idea of iterating the entry set. You should use `SalesConfiguration saleConfiguration = entry.getValue();` instead.

Comment: Might it be that your `ConfigurationCache` could be modified by some other, concurrent thread??

Comment: Could either the call to `generateKeyValueMapFromConfigurations()` or to `saleConfiguration.setMap()` modify the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in your title: **No**, modifying value objects in your `HashMap` while iterating the entry set *cannot* alone produce a `ConcurrentModificationException`. There must be something else going on.

Could either the call to `generateKeyValueMapFromConfigurations()` or to `saleConfiguration.setMap()` modify the map? Might it be that your `ConfigurationCache` could be modified by some other, concurrent thread?? I know I am just guessing, it’s the best we can do with the information at hand.

Comment: Thanks Ole : I was already guessing the last option suggested "ConfigurationCache could be modified by some other," I am trying to find out if this is the culprit , as the exception is not being thrown in every run . 
SO I am guessing there would be some other thread which modifies the configuration cache and at the same time in the loop it is happening here and the exception occurs .
Thanks for ur reply

Comment: If that turns out to be the case, I believe that `ConcurrentHashMap` is an option, as @Prashanth has already mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, ConcurrentHashMap was already suggested but here the challenge for me is to find where the exception is coming from .. I wanted to clarify my concept of HashMap as I was doubting that the modification of key or value's attribute would have lead to this.
Though, the keys should be immutable , here unfortunately someone used the mutable key and modified it too, I wanted to know that the modification of attribute should not be throwing this exception so I wanted to confirm that with veterans over here .

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the culprit.

```
saleConfiguration.setMap(newMap, lastLoadTimestamp);
```

Literally ConcurrentModificationException comes when you update a map entry while iterating through it. Could you please comment out that line and check whether you are getting the exception anymore? If not you need to change the logic so that you do not change the map entries while iterating through them.

Comment: Please don't add code as comments since it's very hard to read. Update the question instead with your new findings.

Comment: But the below Code sample does not throw the exception:

      for (Map.Entry<EmployeeNames, Buildings> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
   EmployeeNames emp= entry.getKey();
   Buildings bld = hm.get(emp);
   
   bld.setFrom("Building1");
  }

Comment: I can even replace the value for the current key within the loop without getting any exception. `olesHashMap.put(entry.getKey(), newValue);` My map contains 4 entries. So I cannot see how modifying the existing value alone should cause the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating entryset. So, modifying the entryset values is not allowed while you are iterating it. Use ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap.

Here is the analysis.

We can modify the key/value's attributes. But we cannot modify the map by adding or deleting elements to the map while we iterate. Suppose a map has five elements, while we iterate it, we can neither add an element to map nor delete an element from map. For this, we should use ConcurrentHashMap.

Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I am modifying the member variable of Value of hashmap<key,value>

Comment: You are iterating ConfigurationCache. You are getting the value SalesConfiguration by passing a key. While you are iterating ConfigurationCache, you are also trying to modify the value SalesConfiguration by calling saleConfiguration.setMap(newMap, lastLoadTimestamp). Declare ConfigurationCache as ConcurrentHashMap. You can update the entries while you iterate. It should solve the problem.

Comment: But the below code sample has the similar case , however no CME in this case

for (Map.Entry<EmployeeNames, Buildings> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
   EmployeeNames emp= entry.getKey();
   Buildings bld = hm.get(emp);
   
   bld.setFrom("Building1");
  }

Comment: Your analysis is quite clear. Does it get us any closer to explaining why the `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs?

Comment: Stacktrace does not get us any clue. But the lines java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1429)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1463)
at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1461) indicate us something went wrong when traversing next node in the collection. Guessing the exact issue from these lines is not sufficient enough.

Comment: Agree, @Prashanth. The exception comes from `next()`, which is called implicitly by the enhanced for loop. This is the time the implicit iterator detects that a modification has taken place, not the time the modification happened.